# Apache rewriterule and rewritecond with 3 domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I have three domains (domain1.es, domain2.com, domain3.com).

I need that:

- domain1.es OR www.domain1.es, show the content of www.domain1.es/catalog
- domain2.com OR www.domain2.com, redirect to www.domain1.es and show the content of www.domain1.es/catalog
- domain3.com OR www.domain3.com, shows the content of www.domain3.com

I'm using cpanel, and I have the domain3.com like an aditional domain, configured to use the `/public_html/domain3.com` folder as web root folder.

I've tried with the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /catalog/
RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^catalog/ catalog%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "domain1\.es" [R=301,L]
```

All the domains are in the same hosting, with the root folder /public_html. Then

- www.domain1.es shows the content of `/public_html/catalog`
- domain1.es shows the content of `/public_html/catalog`
- www.domain2.com shows the content of `/public_html/catalog`
- domain2.com shows the content of `/public_html/catalog`

I am writing the domain3 rules, but I am not sure.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# domain2.es => domain1.es/catalog
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain1.es/catalog%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# domain1.es/foo => domain1.es/catalog/foo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!catalog/).*)$ catalog/$1 [L,NC]

# domain3.es => www.domain3.es
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain3.es/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You missed domain3, and you have missing `(` in last RewriteRule

Comment: `It doesn't work` doesn't help. Please tell me which URI didn't for you.

Comment: [I'm having problems with this comment box, sorry]

Anubhava:

Thanks, but it doesn't work. I have tried: 

    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    
    # domain2.com => domain1.es/catalog
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://domain1.es/catalog%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    # domain1.es/foo => domain1.es/catalog/foo
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.es$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(?!catalog/).*)$ catalog/$1 [L,NC]

With this all the domains are in error.

Comment: Thanks for your second comment, I'm going to try again. But, at the moment, I don't know how to add the domain3 to work properly.

Comment: Now it is ok :-). Thanks for all. I've tried with: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
# domain2.com => www.domain1.es
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain1.es%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# domain1.es/foo => domain1.es/catalog/foo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!catalog/).*)$ catalog/$1 [L,NC]
Now the domain3 works ok :-), without more rules. Do you know a link, to learn from cero, to write htaccess rules? I have tried to search, but all the inf. is a little complicated for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @UlrichPalha: Thanks a lot for checking the code. Nerque, I have made the edits pls check again.